# Is it possible to change a Chrome extension's settings from the popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently writing a Google Chrome extension, and I'm having trouble with certain functionality. I'd like to make it so the user can enable/disable the extension through the pop-up menu using `chrome.storage.sync`. However, I've not been able to get my idea to work.

My code:

```js
// popup.js
function save_options () {
  var enabled = document.getElementById('enabled').checked

  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    enabled: enabled
  })
}

function restore_options () {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    // placeholder value
    enabled: false
  }, function (items) {
    // sub in the real value if it exists
    document.getElementById('enabled').checked = items.enabled
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="bigButton">
        <div id="status">
            <!-- should to "plugin is disabled" when disabled -->
            <h1>Plugin is enabled.</h1>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="enabled" id="enabled"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="refresh">
        <img id="reload" src="img/refresh.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I go about fixing the settings not being written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is not in your `save` method, but the `get`, as a value, it does not receive an object, but a string, or array of strings. Go ahead and try the following:

```
function restore_options () {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('enabled', function (items) {
        //...
    })
}
```

The result here should be that object `items` will contain:

```
{ "enabled": true }
```

In addition, you may want to bulletproof your getter, and use:

```
document.getElementById('enabled').checked = !!items.enabled;
```

This assures you are setting a boolean.

Comment: This worked, thanks very much! I also had to do some refactoring so other functions were not called before my saved data was loaded.